# How to initialize parent class in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I defined this class:

```
export interface Data_Extended extends Data {
  imageurl: string;
}
```

The definition of the Data class is:

```
export interface Data{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
}
```

It's declared:

```
data_Extended:Data_Extended;
```

at some point, I create an instance of the class in the code

```
this.data_Extended =       
return <Data_Extended>{
        super : new Data{id:"1", name:"torro", description: "last automata scene"},
        imageurl:"../repo/config/img_bit.jpeg"
      }
```

But it seems that super not works and I get a syntax error.
So my question is how I access the parent to initialize the instance?

Comment: Start from the docs [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), [classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html). [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Answer (score 1):

The interfaces that you have defined are just interfaces which declare that certain properties must be present.  They can be implemented by classes, but they do not define or create classes.  They don't have a constructor so you cannot create them with `new`.

The beauty of typescript interfaces is that they can be implemented by either classes or plain javascript objects.  So can instantiate it just by creating an object with the right properties.

```
const extendedData: Data_Extended = {
    id: "1",
    name: "torro",
    description: "last automata scene",
    imageurl: "../repo/config/img_bit.jpeg"
};
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/4WyQbW)